# Can't install passanger mod_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger

I am trying to install passenger server for my rails application using this guide http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html The problem occurs in step `passenger-install-apache2-module`.
When I run this command I get this -

```
WARNING: Apache doesn't seem to be compiled with the 'prefork', 'worker' or 'event' MPM
```

How can I solve this? My OS is Ubuntu 13.10 and I have already installed all necessary packages: apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-mpm-worker libapache2-mod-passenger

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/546924/installing-phusion-passenger-4-0-20-on-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brad Werth said, https://serverfault.com/questions/546924/installing-phusion-passenger-4-0-20-on-ubuntu-13-10 provides a solution.

This problem is caused by a bug in Phusion Passenger's passenger-install-apache2-module program. Ubuntu 13.10 changed the way the `httpd -V` command works, so passenger-install-apache2-module was unable to correctly detect the MPM for your Apache, resulting in an incorrect warning message. You can safely ignore this warning.

I've fixed the problem in Phusion Passenger now. The fix will be included in version 4.0.34: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/commit/6f5af46de7cb80dd88ef3b35c7c5c4bfbfa0cfd3